# How do I create a foreign key that references my generated IdentityUser entity (ApplicationUser) in Blazor Webassembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am trying to add a foreign key into my 'Item' entity that references the 'ApplicationUser' entity generated by identity scaffolding in my Blazor Webassembly project.

**ApplicationUser Entity:**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace XXX.Server.Models
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string? UserFirstName { get; set; }
        public string? UserLastName { get; set;}
        public DateTime UserRegDate { get;set; }
        public string? UserDescription { get; set; }
        public DateTime UserLastOnline { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Item Entity:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace XXX.Shared.Domain
{
    public class Item : BaseDomainModel
    {
        public int ItemPrice { get; set; }
        public string? Condition { get; set; }
        public DateTime ItemDate { get; set; }
        public string? ItemDescription { get; set; }
        public string? ItemLocation { get; set; }
        public int ItemLikes { get; set; }
        public int ItemClicks { get; set; }
        public int ItemStatus { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public virtual Category ? Category { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public virtual *ApplicationUser* ? ApplicationUser { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Above, ApplicationUser is highlighted with error CS0246.

Note that ApplicationUser.cs and Item.cs are in seperate files, with the ApplicationUser.cs file in the Server folder and the Item.cs file in my Shared folder. I am unable to change the locations of these files.

Comment: Are both files in the same or in different assemblies? Do you missing a using directive?

Comment: The error requires you add a project reference,if it would cause cycle reference,consider moving your ApplicationUser  to shared project(root level project)

Comment: @Caveman74 I think the files are in different assemblies (one is in shared, one is in server), how would write the using directive for this? Or is referencing not a possibility across assemblies.

Comment: @RuikaiFeng I used scaffolding to create the identity server, will moving it to the shared project cause any issues?

Comment: It would be ok if you add project reference  properly